# How to directly send *.php.html files to browser without passing throught PHP? (Apache)

Tags: apache-2.2, php

on my Apache/PHP server, file test.php.html is parsed by PHP, while test.html is not. 
PHPDOC create a lot of *.php.html files, with a XML header wich is a pain for PHP parser, but how to tell Apache not to pass *.php.html file to PHP and just send back the file to browser?

My php.conf file

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so
</IfModule>
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php
```

What can I do?

Thanks,
Bests regards
Cédric

Comment: There appears to be a similar question on stackoverflow that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189780/why-is-apache-executing-php-html-files-as-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the accepted answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189780/why-is-apache-executing-php-html-files-as-php

I replaced

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

by

```
<FilesMatch \.cgi$>
SetHandler cgi-script
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your Apache configuration or in a ".htaccess" file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php\.html$">
    SetHandler None
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Does not work for me, sorry.